# adding google analytics jar via SBT to scala project

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, google-analytics-api, sbt-idea

I want to add google analytics package/jar to a scala project with SBT. However I cannot find the URL of the project on http://mvnrepository.com/
I've also tried looking for it on google forums but to no avail.

I'm thinking of downloading the jar and adding it to sbt as an unmanaged jar. I think a jar is found at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/com/google/apis/google-api-services-analytics/v3-1.3.3-beta?repo=mavenrepo&r=5f31c0ad06088b1762f414890cef93ba177ad4b8
but this is a maven repository. Now, instead of downloading the jar, I'd like to let SBT handle downloading of libs, but for this I need the URL of the maven repository that I just posted the link to where the google code is.

**Question**
Is there a way to figure out the URL to the maven repository where google analytics jar is stored (from the URL above)? Any other repository that has a copy of google analytics will also do.

Comment: Will none of the ones here work?  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-analytics

Comment: @waffleparadox that's pretty much what I was trying to find! A search on that site for `google analytics` does not return that URL. If you don't mind me asking, how did you find it?

Comment: Explained a bit more in answer form, but in this case I just googled the artifact name.  :)  Weird that mvnrepository's search engine doesn't turn it up, even when you search the exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-analytics

In this case I just googled the artifact name ("google-api-services-analytics") but the structure of maven repositories tends to be very predictable.  If you go one level up in the google code page you linked and check out maven-metadata.xml, that will tell you the group and artifact to look for in a repository.